Get the thumbnail of a YouTube video with React Native
I'm creating an app and I'm trying to extract the thumbnail of each youtube video and display them on a list, using a flatlist.
This is the function I'm using to fetch the thumbnail data:
async function getThumbnailURL(videoId) {
   const response = await fetch(`https://www.youtube.com/oembed?format=json&url=${videoId}`);
   const data = await response.json();
   return data.thumbnail_url;
}

This is my renderItem function:
const renderItem =({item}) => {
const thumbnailURL =  getThumbnailURL(item.id);
console.log(typeof(thumbnailURL))

return(
<View style={styles.video}> 
                    <Image
                        source={{
                          uri: thumbnailURL
                        }}
                       
                    />
                     <View >
                        <Text>{item.desc}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
);
}

What displays when 'console.log(thumbnailURL)' runs for the 9 youtube ID's is
(NOBRIDGE) LOG  {"_h": 0, "_i": 0, "_j": null, "_k": null}
(NOBRIDGE) LOG  {"_h": 0, "_i": 0, "_j": null, "_k": null}
(NOBRIDGE) LOG  {"_h": 0, "_i": 0, "_j": null, "_k": null}
(NOBRIDGE) LOG  {"_h": 0, "_i": 0, "_j": null, "_k": null}
(NOBRIDGE) LOG  {"_h": 0, "_i": 0, "_j": null, "_k": null}
(NOBRIDGE) LOG  {"_h": 0, "_i": 0, "_j": null, "_k": null}
(NOBRIDGE) LOG  {"_h": 0, "_i": 0, "_j": null, "_k": null}
(NOBRIDGE) LOG  {"_h": 0, "_i": 0, "_j": null, "_k": null}
(NOBRIDGE) LOG  {"_h": 0, "_i": 0, "_j": null, "_k": null}

and this is the flatlist I'm using to display all the thumbnails
 <View>
  <FlatList
    data={VIDEOS}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
   
  />
   <Text></Text>
  </View>

When I run the app, this error shows
Value for url cannot be cast from readablenativemap to string

thank you for your help in advance
